# Absolute positioned button not positioned in it's parent DIV

Tags: html, css

In the code below I added input button to the leftPane div. 
Here I have two div's/ Left 80% and right 20%.
Now I want to position this button to be vertically in the middle and on the right side in the leftPane.
But it when I set 'right:0;' it goes to the right side of the browser, and not of the right side of the leftPane.
Why?

```
<body style="overflow:hidden;">

        <div  style="background: #ff0000; position: fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;">
            <div id="leftPage" style="width:80%; height:100%;background:#00ff00; float:left;text-align:center;">
                <img src="http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs45/f/2009/106/c/1/HD_Nature_Wallpapers_by_CurtiXs.jpg" alt="test" style="max-width:90%; max-height:90%;"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Next" style="width:40px;height:70px;position:absolute;top:50%;right:0;"/>
            </div>
            <div id="rightPane" style="width:20%; height:100%;background:#0000ff; float:left;">
                <div id="commentBox" style="background:#dddddd; width:90%; height: 50px;">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here..." />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have the parent `<div style="position: relative;">` otherwise your absolute positioning is defaulting to your `<body>`

To clarify, set `#leftPage` to relative positioning.

Comment: Actually, an `absolute` positioned element's position will be calculated relatively to the first parent that has a `position` other than `static` (so not just `relative`) - it is called a *containing block*. If there is no parent like that, it will be calculated relatively to the body. In the OP's case, there is a `position: fixed` div, which is of course `100%`, so "visually" it's the same as the body, but not the body is used for the calculation.

Comment: [Great article about this topic on Dev.Opera](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/37-css-absolute-and-fixed-positioning/#containingblocks)